# Reversing subtraction in polynomial division?

Tags: polynomials, geometric-series

I'm reading the derivation of the geometric sum formula here:
http://www.purplemath.com/modules/series7.htm

It says that the polynomial property:
$$\frac{x^n-1}{x-1} = 1+x+x^2+...+x^{n-1}$$ (i.e. any polynomial of the form $x^n-1$ is divisible by $x-1$)

Applies to the geometric series $1+r+r^2+...+r^{n-1}$ producing:
$$\frac{1-r^n}{1-r}$$
where the subtraction has been reversed.

I can't see why this reversing is legal.

Comment: $\frac{x^n-1}{x-1}=\frac{-\left(1-x^n\right)}{-(1-x)}=\frac{1-x^n}{1-x}$.

Comment: Because for any fraction, $\;\dfrac ab=\dfrac{-a}{-b}$.

Comment: Multiply by $1 = \frac{-1}{-1}$.

Comment: Ok, but why is this useful?

Comment: Because you might want to keep both the top and bottom of the fraction positive. If $r<1$ then it's natural to write $\dfrac{1-r^n}{1-r}$.

Comment: By the way, it is not the case that any polynomial is divisible by $x-1$. However, it is the case that any polynomial of the form $x^n-1$ is divisible by $x-1$.

Comment: It should have been pointed out to you in school that $b-a$ is the negative of $a-b$.

Comment: It's just the polynomial powers and how they affect sign causing a bit of confusion here.

Comment: That's, what signs do $r^n$ and $r$ have? Which of course doesn't matter, but did cause confusion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's exactly the same, because
$$
\frac{r^n-1}{r-1}=\frac{-(1-r^n)}{-(1-r)}=\frac{1-r^n}{1-r}
$$
Why is it written this way? Because, if $|r|<1$, then
$$
\lim_{n\to\infty}r^n=0
$$
and so
$$
\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{1-r^n}{1-r}=\frac{1-0}{1-r}=\frac{1}{1-r}
$$
Of course it would be the same writing
$$
\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{r^n-1}{r-1}=\frac{0-1}{r-1}=
\frac{-1}{-(1-r)}=\frac{1}{1-r}
$$
Just a matter of opinion about what's the clearer presentation.